# iterate or loop through class parameters

Tags: puppet

Is there a way with puppet code to use looping constructs to iterate or loop through class parameters. Assuming i have a class named "test" I can utilize specific variables using what "seems" like a hash construct (eg: $test::var1, $test::var2) however i cannot seem to loop/iterate over $test as if it were a hash.

As an example:

```
class test (
  $var1 = 'test123',
  $var2 = 'test456',
) {

  # Statically Utilize Class Parameter
  notify { "Output of var1 is: ${test::var1}": }

  # Statically Utilize Class Parameter
  notify { "Output of var2 is: ${test::var2}": }

  # Loop through all Class Parameters (Doesn't Work)
  $test.each |$stuffkey, $stuffvalue| {
    notify { "Looping Construct: ${stuffkey}, ${stuffvalue}": }
  }
}

class { 'test': }
```

Is there any workable way to "loop" or "iterate" over all key/values that are class parameters on a specific class?

I have tried several permutations of $test::, $test, and similar. I can't seem to figure out how to iterate over the class parameters.

Comment: There may be a way to do this, but you should probably also take a step back and think about why you want to do this and what you hope to achieve. Why not convert the individual param `String` into a single `Hash[String, String]`?

Comment: I can't definitively say that there is no way to do this, especially if we allow the possibility of writing and calling custom functions, but the Puppet manifest language does not define any mechanism that would support it.

Comment: Note also that in your particular example, `$test` is a *variable* with no initial value assigned.  It belongs to class test, in whose body it appears, but it does not represent that class.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way with puppet code to use looping constructs to iterate or loop through class parameters.

Taking "with puppet code" to mean relying only on the features of the Puppet manifest language and Puppet's built-in functions, and without first building an iterable collection manually, **no**.  You can access individual variables, including parameters, of a class that has already been declared or that is presently being processed ...

```
  include test
  notify { "test::var1: ${test::var1}": }
```

... but there is no particular facility for obtaining a collection of its parameters (or more generally its variables) as an iterable object.

> I can utilize specific variables using what "seems" like a hash construct (eg: $test::var1, $test::var2) however i cannot seem to loop/iterate over $test as if it were a hash.

Those are the fully-qualified forms of the names of the class's variables, which include its parameters.  In them, the class name is serving the role of a *namespace* identifier. I'm unsure what about that form says specifically "hash" to you, but it is not a hash, at least not in the sense of the Puppet data type by that name.  There is no defined mechanism for enumerating or iterating over the names in any particular namespace.

It is furthermore unclear to me what advantage is to be gained by performing such an iteration.  If you want parameter data in the form of a hash, then you can always require it to be presented in that form in the first place.  Then you can iterate over a parameter value instead of over the class itself.  Or if requiring parameters in that form seems unnatural for your particular purpose, then I submit that the iteration you propose must itself be just as unnatural.

Answer (score 0):

Puppet is not the best for iterating, but there are different approaches. If you head to the official documentation for Puppet 7, you'll see, that you can use ".each" on a *block of code*, e.g.:

```
['a','b','c'].each |Integer $index, String $value| { notice("${index} = ${value}") }
```

As you want to iterate over a list of class parameters, I'd consider using an array/hash for them, so having one class parameter with an array/hash holding the items you want to iterate over (code untested):

```
class test (
  $vars = [ var1 => 'test123', var2 => 'test456']
) {
  $vars.each |$key, $value| {
    notify { "Looping Construct: ${key}, ${value}": }
  }
}

class { 'test': }
```

The older approach for iterating in Puppet was using defines which, in your case, would mean putting the code in a define as described in the documentation liked above, too:

```
define puppet::binary::symlink ($binary = $title) {
  file {"/usr/bin/${binary}":
    ensure => link,
    target => "/opt/puppetlabs/bin/${binary}",
  }
}
$binaries = ['facter', 'hiera', 'mco', 'puppet', 'puppetserver']

puppet::binary::symlink { $binaries: }
```

This would not reveal all parameters at once but might do the trick depending on your specific requirment.